# ¿Cual es la manera correcta de escapar caracteres para enviar un json mediante rest?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, rest, shopify

estoy usando la API REST de shopify para actualizar algunos metadatos de mis clientes.
La peticion es la siguiente:

Ojo, cambie el nombre de mi tienda en la url por my-store por privacidad, pero estoy conciente de que ahi debe ir el nombre de mi tienda.

```
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: `https://my-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/customers/${req.query.id}/metafields.json`,
  headers: {
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": offline_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: req.body,
})
  .then((data) => {
    res.json(data.data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("ocurrio un error")
    res.json(error)
  });
```

No he tenido problemas al pasar datos de tipo string por el data como lo llama axios o el body como se llama realmente en rest.

El problema esta cuando le paso un json en el body, la API no me actualiza el metadato.

Investigando descubri que debo de escapar las comillas de mi "key" value para que funcione la peticion, de la siguiente manera.

```
{
"metafield":{
    "namespace": "member",
    "key": "days_open",
    "value": "{\"days_open\":[\"wednesday\",\"saturday\", \"monday\", \"tuesday\", \"sunday\"]}",
    "type": "json"
}}
```

Busque alguna funcion para escapar arreglos de esa forma pero no encontre nada, asi que con algunas lineas de codigo logre el resultado que esperaba.

```
let val = JSON.stringify(req.body.metafield.value)
req.body.metafield.value = val.replace(/\"/g, '\\"')

console.log(req.body.metafield.value);
//result {\"days_open\":[\"monday\",\"tuesday\",\"wednesday\",\"saturday\",\"sunday\"]}
```

Asi que volvi a hacer mi peticion y me aparece un error, asi que procedo a mostrar mi error con un console.log()

Y descubri que la seccion de data se cambia por lo siguiente. Se me agregan muchas barras invertidas por alguna razon, alguna idea de porque este comportamiento? o de que manera deberia de abordar esta peticion?

```
 data: '{"metafield":{"namespace":"member","key":"days_open","value":"{\\\\\\"days_open\\\\\\":[\\\\\\"monday\\\\\\",\\\\\\"tuesday\\\\\\",\\\\\\"wednesday\\\\\\",\\\\\\"saturday\\\\\\",\\\\\\"sunday\\\\\\"]}","type":"json"}}'
```

Nota: Por cierto olvide mencionarlo pero estoy trabajando esta funcionalidad del lado del servidor con node js (asi me exige que haga las peticiones shopify desde un backend), tengo ya varias peticiones echas con axios a la api de shopify, y esta misma peticion funciona si la hago mediante postman o si hardcodeo el body con axios escapando los caracteres de value como se menciona mas arriba).

Shopify tiene un paquete para node JS para hacer esto mas facil, pero debido a ciertas circunstancias del proyecto esta opcion quedo sin poder usarse, asi que no es posible hacer uso de esta herramienta para los mas entendidos en shopify.

Agradezco sus respuestas, saludos.

Comment: En teoría, con `JSON.stringify(objeto)` no necesitas escapar las comillas ni manipular de otra forma la cadena resultante.